# django media_url with ajax

Tags: ajax, django

I have a page where users can search for other users. The search is done with ajax and the results are looped through in a template and then placed onto the page. The search works perfectly, but MEDIA_URL is showing up empty in the results and breaks all the profile pictures for the results. The MEDIA_URL tag works everywhere else on the site, just not in this template. I am using pyjade for my templates.

python to return results at end of search

```
#render template to string, pass to js to add to page
r = render_to_string('users/search_ajax_template.jade', { 'results': p })
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'results': r, 'errcode': 0}))
```

search_ajax_template.jade

```
- for result in results
    div.result-wrapper
        a(href='/profiles/{{ result.path }}', class='result')
            img(src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ result.prof_pic }}')
            div.result-name {{ result.name }}
```

Comment: I'm not sure on this hence the comment but you could try passing render_to_string a RequestContext instance, i.e.: `from django.template import RequestContext; r = render_to_string('users/search_ajax_template.jade', { 'results': p }, RequestContext(request))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add MEDIA_URL to the context dictionary for rendering.

Option 1:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
...
...
...
r = render_to_string('users/search_ajax_template.jade', { 'results': p }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Option 2:

```
from settings import MEDIA_URL
...
...
...
r = render_to_string('users/search_ajax_template.jade', { 'results': p, 'MEDIA_URL': MEDIA_URL })
```